# How to aggregate the first non-NULL value in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a complex permissions hierarchy but will try to simplify this question as much as possible. Given a table `permission` which contains the columns `permissionID`; `read` and `write` (as nullable Integers), I am looking for a way to determine the effective permissions, e.g. given multiple `permission` entries I'd like to retrieve the first (very important as I am sorting them by `permissionID`) `read` and `write` entries that are not NULL. Ideally, this would be done using an aggregate function, but there are none that do what I require.

Example:

```
permissionID | read | write
----------------------------
1            | NULL | NULL
2            | NULL | False
3            | False| True
4            | True | True

SELECT first_not_null(read), first_not_null(write) FROM permission ORDER BY permissionID;

| read  | write |
-----------------
| False | False |
```

In this case `first_not_null` would be the imaginary aggregate function that would yield the result that I want. What I'm trying to achieve with this is avoiding multiple queries in order to create this "effective permission" result (the real thing has way more columns than `read` and `write`).

I'd appreciate any kind of assistance or poining in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, Postgres doesn't support `ignore null`s.  One method is kind of a hack on array aggregate -- aggregate the values into an array, remove the `NULL` values and take the first one:

```
select (array_remove(array_agg(read order by permissionId), NULL))[1],
       (array_remove(array_agg(write order by permissionId), NULL))[1]
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8d4bbc06e23840438e6a7320bc24c3ae) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is what I was looking for. Doesn't look pretty, but it does what it's supposed to!